# Attach Watin to an existing browser always times out

Tags: watin

I am trying to attach Watin to an existing instance of Internet Explorer 9. The trouble is no matter what I try it seems to just timeout. The code I am using is:

```
Settings.AttachToBrowserTimeOut = 240;
Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut = 240;
Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut = 240;   

Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Google"), 240);
```

This code is what is in the Watin [guide here](http://watinandmore.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/browserattachto-and-iattachto.html) minus the timeout adjustments I have tried. I have also tried setting the code to run x86 not any cpu but still not working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you write in is missing the single threaded `ApartmentState`. The easiest way to fix this is to add `[STAThread]` above the method where you're trying to use that code.

For example this:

```
//[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Google"), 5);
}
```

acts like you described. When you uncomment the `[STAThread]`

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Google"), 5);
}
```

it works as intented.

Comment: I got caught out because I set the main thread to STAThread but had the Watin code run an event handler. Event handlers are MTA and can't be overridden as far as I can see. I solved it by launching a thread from the event handler.